# how to get participant id on registration thank-you page

Tags: registration, online-registration, participants

How could I get the participant ID and the corresponding contact ID on the event registration thank-you page? E.g. is there a field (or piece of code) I can insert in /templates/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/DisplayProfile.tpl ?

For participant ID I tried the following but to no avail:

```
<div class="participant-id hidden">{$participant.id}</div>
```

Thank you for any tips

Comment: you can try inserting `{debug}` at any line in the file and check the variables that are populating for the template file.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, @jitendra-fuzion, I did what you suggested, and the only helpful variable I see is an array {$participantIDs} ... we only allow one participant so how could I grab the first (and only) item in the array?

Comment: OK - found a good-enough answer for now - posting it below; thank you again for the tip

Answer (score 3):

the following did the trick - works in this situation well enough as we only allow registering one participant:

```
{$participantIDs.0}
```

The above grabs the participant ID of the first (and only in our case) participant

Comment: I found a PHP-only approach to get the participant_id. @ me if interested.

Comment: @dsmith63 sure thing - please do share. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The participant_id can be accessed on the event registration thank you page in two different ways -- by using Smarty template variables when the user is logged in or by using session variables when the user is anonymous. Both approaches work when used inside the "civicrmBuildForm" hook.

**1) User logged in**

```
add_action( 'civicrm_buildForm', 'getParticipantId' );

function getParticipantId() {
    $template = (array) CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
    $event = $template['_tpl_vars']['event'];

    $participant = civicrm_api3('Participant', 'getsingle', [
        'sequential' => 1,
        'contact_id' => "user_contact_id",
        'event_id' => $event['id'],
    ]);

    echo $participant['id'];
}
```

**2) Anonymous user**

```
add_action( 'civicrm_buildForm', 'getParticipantId' );

function getCrmFromSession($session) {
    if (!empty($session)) {
        $seshAry = (array) $session;
        $seshKey = array_keys($seshAry)[1];
        $CiviCRM = json_decode(json_encode($seshAry[$seshKey]), true)['CiviCRM'];

        if ( !empty($CiviCRM['CRM_Utils_Recent']) && isset($CiviCRM['CRM_Utils_Recent'][0]['id']) ) {
            $CiviCRM['participant_id'] = $CiviCRM['CRM_Utils_Recent'][0]['id'];
        }

        return $CiviCRM;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

function getParticipantId() {
    $CiviCRM = getCrmFromSession(CRM_Core_Session::singleton());

    echo $CiviCRM['participant_id'];
}
```

- I appended a template to the Thank You template with the data related to participant_id.
- In my case, the BuildForm hook lives in my theme's functions.php file.

Comment: @MtnPavlas, hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the code, @dsmith63 - super helpful